# Laravel Mod for Google App Engine is not working on Windows

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel

I am trying to use laravel php framework on google appengine platform, I have installed the App Engine SDK on my Windows 8.1. I have added the path for SDK. I have PHP installed from Xampp. Then i cloned this repo: https://github.com/faiyaz26/Laravel-4-for-Google-App-Engine
on my PC and tried to run it. It shows this error: 
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
PHP Startup: apc_fcntl_create: could not open C:\WINDOWS.apc.a05860

Though i can run other demo php app from Appengine on my local pc.

I tried to use the given php executables from GAE SDK but no use. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but try adding

```
apc.cache_by_default = "0"
```

to a `php.ini` file in the root of the AppEngine project, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google App Engine Launcher be sure open it using "Run as administrator" before you run your app.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
apc.enabled = 0
```

in the php.ini file.

APC is a cache in PHP for speeding up execution of scripts and temporarily storing data between requests. I guess Google does not use it as they might do their own optimizations.